Excel Labs Python Function Not Recognized (Name Error)
I am using an Enterprise version of Excel, so I cannot join the Beta to get the latest Excel feature with Python.  I do have access to the Excel Labs Add In with the initial version of Python for Excel.  When I try to use it, it won't recognize the function (PY) though, as it always results in a #NAME? error.  What am I doing wrong?  The IDE looks like everything works until I go to run it.

The documentation online is now all pointing to the Beta feature so I can't figure this out with the current MS documentation.  It doesn't matter what I write in the IDE--even what is written in the function's official documentation--the error is clearly because it's not seeing the function name.  This same thing is happening to my colleague, so I am expecting this to be a bug of some sort, but hoping it can be salvaged.  I do have Anaconda installed but by colleague does not.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
